# How do you name the "same" entity in different tiers of an application?

Tags: naming

You've got an N-tier application which deals with companies, so you've got a table called Company, an object in your DAL called `MyApp.DAL.Company`, an object in your application layer called `MyApp.Core.Company`, and in your service contract called `MyApp.Contract.Company`, and in your client proxy called `MyApp.ServiceReference.Company`, and in your client model called `MyClient.Model.Company`. You've probably also got one in your viewmodel called `MyClient.ViewModel.Company`.

Questions:

1. How do you deal with the boilerplate code that converts from `Company` to `Company` at each layer?
2. How do you deal with the fact that they've all got the same name? This is a problem in those layers where you have to deal with both (e.g. in the service contract implementation), but also in unit, integration and (less so) system tests.

Comment: I like the idea of same name name, different namespaces. Rationale is that the Entity should represent a business domain name - reworking it at different. If your namespaces are long, your dev language might support namespace aliasing to sanitise (e.g. Dal.Entity, Contract.Entity etc)